# Sending BTC with Coinbase's API?

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

```
https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transactions/send_money?api_key=xxx
```

I have that URL but after the api_key paramter what comes next (I blocked out my API Key so people can't access my BTC)?

Can someone give me an example of how to properly use coinbase's send_money API?

Comment: When I google `coinbase API documentation` I see plenty of examples. Do they not work for you?

Comment: Read them except none of them make much sense to me and I asked a specific question.

Comment: I code against their API but not in PHP. Their docs with samples have been spot on for me. so if the docs don't help you I'd check out their PHP library https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a PHP environment handy to test this with but I think it would go like this:

Get their PHP library: https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/Coinbase.php');

// Create an application at https://coinbase.com/oauth/applications and set these  values accordingly
$_CLIENT_ID = "83a481f96bf28ea4bed1ee8bdc49ba4265609efa40d40477c2a57e913c479065";
$_CLIENT_SECRET = "a8dda20b94d09e84e8fefa5e7560133d9c5af9da93ec1d3e79ad0843d2920bbb";

// Note: your redirect URL should use HTTPS.
$_REDIRECT_URL = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$coinbaseOauth = new Coinbase_OAuth($_CLIENT_ID, $_CLIENT_SECRET, $_REDIRECT_URL);

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {

  // Request tokens
  $tokens = $coinbaseOauth->getTokens($_GET['code']);

  // The user is now authenticated! Access and refresh tokens are in $tokens
  // Store these tokens safely, and use them to make Coinbase API requests in the future.
  // For example:
  $coinbase = new Coinbase($coinbaseOauth, $tokens);

  try {
    echo 'Balance: ' . $coinbase->sendMoney($to, $amount, $notes=null, $userFee=null, $amountCurrency=null) . '<br>';
    echo $coinbase->createButton("Alpaca socks", "10.00", "CAD")->embedHtml;
  } catch (Coinbase_TokensExpiredException $e) {
    $newTokens = $coinbaseOauth->refreshTokens($tokens);
    // Store $newTokens and retry request
  }
} else {

  // Redirect to Coinbase authorization page
  // The provided parameters specify the access your application will have to the
  // user's account; for a full list, see https://coinbase.com/docs/api/overview
  // You can pass as many scopes as you would like
  echo "<a href=\"" . $coinbaseOauth->createAuthorizeUrl("balance", "buttons") . "\">Connect with Coinbase</a>";
}
```

Here is the send money code

```
public function sendMoney($to, $amount, $notes=null, $userFee=null, $amountCurrency=null)
{
    $params = array( "transaction[to]" => $to );

    if($amountCurrency !== null) {
        $params["transaction[amount_string]"] = $amount;
        $params["transaction[amount_currency_iso]"] = $amountCurrency;
    } else {
        $params["transaction[amount]"] = $amount;
    }

    if($notes !== null) {
        $params["transaction[notes]"] = $notes;
    }

    if($userFee !== null) {
        $params["transaction[user_fee]"] = $userFee;
    }

    return $this->post("transactions/send_money", $params);
}
```